# Facebook app - implementing notifications

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, notifications

I'm writing a Facebook app which needs to send reminders to users at set dates in the future. When searching for how to implement these notifications I find a lot of talk about how Facebook removed app notifications and you now either have to use counters or send the user emails. Emails I understand, but there's nothing about "counters" in the graph API docs or the PHP SDK. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old Facebook rest api had a method called "notifications.send" which is what I think you are referring to but that has been completely removed and you won't see any documentation on it from Facebook's end.  You can view the [old documentation](http://web.archive.org/web/20091117203611/http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Notifications.send) through the wayback machine.  There currently is no other good alternative to this old method besides email/Facebook messaging unfortunately.